# Application specific binary data in sqlite DB outside of tables

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to store application specific binary data at a fixed/computable offset?

I have a situation where I have 2 programs, one which can read the sqlite DB, one which cannot but would like to access some bytes (~10 bytes) from the same DB file.

Without using sqlite VFS, possibly.
I've already thought about storing a big magic string + the real data inside a table. But then the other program would need to read the whole DB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite database file format [is documented](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html).

If you put the bytes into a special table, you do not need to read too many pages (but it's still rather complicated to parse the B-tree/record formats).

Alternatively, put the bytes into a table *definition*:

```
CREATE TABLE unused(unused /* MAGIC:xxxxxxxxxx */);
```

This will be in the first page as long as there aren't too many tables (if the `sqlite_master` table gets too big, it overflows from the first page).

Alternatively, there are (as of now) twenty unused bytes in the database [header](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header).